# Python: intercommunication between shells

Tags: python, shell, process, resume, pausing-execution

A **Python** program is running on a *shell*, how to communicate with it using *another Python shell*?

Let say we have started running a very long simulation which is going well on a shell. We realised a need to capture the current values, say, in a `numpy` array.

How to *pause* the simulation, *capture* desired values and *resume* using another Python shell?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a package to work with subprocesses, capture an output: http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/

For instance to capture an output, you can `check_output`

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-1'])
print 'Have %d bytes in output' % len(output)
print output
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [IPython](http://www.ipython.org). It runs code in one or more kernels, which can then be communicated with by different subprocesses. All of the values in the running kernel can be shared, allowing you to do exactly what you're looking to do. Sites like [Wakari](https://www.wakari.io) offer free IPython Notebook instances so you can experiment.